# Is it possible to specify a XML node name and depth with attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I would like to serialize a C# class structure out to XML and provide for a specific node name without having to have a bunch of nested classes. Is that possible using attributes?

For example say I have the following XML:

```
<OuterItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <InnerItem>
        <ItemValue>something i need</ItemValue>
    </InnerItem>
</OuterItem>
```

I have an XML serialization method that looks like this:

```
public static string XmlSerializeToString<T>(T value)
{
    if (value == null) { return null; }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = false;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Would I have to have a C# class structure like this?

```
public class OuterItem
{
    public InnerItem InnerItem { get; set; }
}

public class InnerItem
{
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

Or is it at all possible to declare how far down in the XML document my node should be with something like this (pseudo code):

```
public class OuterItem
{
    [XmlNode("InnerItem\ItemValue")]
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use xpath or similar expressions in XmlNode attributes. Your choice of attributes to [control xml serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/83y7df3e.aspx) is very limited.

You can use following hack to deserialize xml you have:

```
public class OuterItem
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="ItemValue", Type=typeof(string))]
    [XmlArray]
    public string[] InnerItem
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var item = new OuterItem { InnerItem = new[]{"AAA"} };
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OuterItem));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out,item);
    }
}
```

This would produce following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OuterItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <InnerItem>
    <ItemValue>AAA</ItemValue>
  </InnerItem>
</OuterItem>
```

Another possible solution is to use XmlTextAttribute, get inner xml into property of XmlNode type, and parse manually.